# TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

serv=Service(executable_path="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2.3\geckodriver.exe")
driver=webdriver.Firefox(service = serv)
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2.3\geckodriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.amazon.in")
```

i tried to launch the application but i am getting an error please resolve my code

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox(service = serv)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

Comment: As the **error** described in message,, `service` is not a valid parameter, then you instead may need to use `options = FirefoxOptions()` ,  `options.add_argument("-service")`, `options.add_argument("C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2.3\geckodriver.exe")` and `webdriver.Firefox(options=options)`